# white dots below HTML text

Tags: css, html

My output in website has dots below text :

[image]

why is it coming and how to remove it?

**HTML**

```
<p align = "center"><font size = "4.5" color="#979C91"><a href="customer.html"><span class="fa fa-pencil"> Customers</span></a>
&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
<a href="business.html"><span class="fa fa-pencil"> Business</font></span></p></a>
```

**CSS**

```
.fa {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.fa.solo{}
.fa.solo span {
    display: none;
}
.fa:before {
    display:inline-block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
}
.fa-pencil:before{
    content:"\f040"
}
```

Comment: Probably a class you use have some border dotted

Comment: Can you tell the url?

Comment: Please show all the codes in `fa fa-pencil` as well

Comment: Probably your `fa` or `fa-pencil` classes have something like `border-bottom: 1px dotted white;`. Please add corresponding css code.

Comment: i used fa from http://fontawesome.io

Comment: even when i put outside class just below <body still i get those lines>

Comment: I have written the CSS file content in the question

Comment: The code posted does not produce the problem. And the HTML code is seriously malformed (invalid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a dotted border being applied to the bottom of that element. To remove it, you can apply the following CSS to remove it:

```
border-bottom: none;
```

Without being able to see the rest of the code, it's hard to say what caused this to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css file

```
a{
text-decoration:none;}
```

The css code of the website (http://fontawesome.io/) that you are referring to is

```
a:focus {
outline: thin dotted;
}
a:active, a:hover {
outline: 0 none;
}
```

and if this is in your coding then that is the problem.

It is not you .fa class that is the problem..

Comment: it has text-decoration as none..plus after removing the .fa class i still get those doted line

Comment: do you have a link to the site you are working on, or sen me an email marinus@aboutit.co.za with your css coding I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

try debugging. right click your browser then inspect element the field. In right portion you will see in what file the text-decoration is declared.

screenshot: http://d.pr/i/PoDI

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
> <p align = "center"> <font size = "4.5" color="#979C91"><a
> href="customer.html" style="text-decoration: none"><span class="fa
> fa-pencil"> Customers</span></a>   <a href="business.html"
> style="text-decoration: none"><span class="fa fa-pencil">
> Business</font></span></p></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with .a in css

```
a
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: inherit;
        border-bottom: dotted 1px rgba(128,128,128,0.5);
```

I removed the border-bottom and now I don't get any dots below.