# Add a single dot below each character using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a way to create the following effect with CSS.

[image: 1 dot at each char]

I found some solutions for putting dots below the text ([white dots below HTML text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398193/white-dots-below-html-text)), but I don't want "dotted underlining", I want every character to have just a single dot below it. Also the dot should increase with the font-size of the text (although if needed, I could mess with JS to fix that).

How could I achieve that?

Comment: What about making your own font with dots? :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You cannot style a continuous block of text on per-character basis using CSS *yet*.

*(There might be support for that in the future, as @Oriol points out in his answer. I'm only dealing with the current situation here.)*

You can style your code on per-element basis, so if you enclose each and every one of your characters in a separate element (with `char` class), you could add the dot using something like:

```
.char {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.char::before {
    content: '.';
    display: inline-block;

    /* position the dot underneath the character */
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -0.5em;
    left: 0;

    /* center the dot horizontally */
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;

    /* ... (style the dot to your liking) */
}
```

This would make the DOM incredibly messy, but it would meet your requirements (scale with font-size, etc).

Comment: You can create a simple JS code to split them into spans: `$('#wrap').html( "<span>"+ $('#wrap').html().split("").join("</span><span>")+"</span>" )`

Comment: @Martijn This will only work if `#wrap` only contains text nodes.

Comment: Splitting DOM text into characters is a separate exercise with a variety of solutions. I wouldn't worry about it here.

Comment: @Oriol: You are right, but writing a 100% solution as a omment would've been a bit much :P Just showing the concept of the idea :)

Answer (score 25):

[CSS Text Decoration Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/) defines those properties:

- [`text-emphasis-style`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-css-text-decor-3-20130801/#text-emphasis-style-property)

  > This property applies emphasis marks to the element's text. [...]
  >   The marks are drawn once for each character.
- [`text-emphasis-position`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-css-text-decor-3-20130801/#text-emphasis-position)

  > This property describes where emphasis marks are drawn at.

When browsers support that, you will be able to use

```css
text-emphasis-style: dot;
text-emphasis-position: under left; /* or `under right` */
```

```css
body {
  text-emphasis-style: dot;
  text-emphasis-position: under left;
  -webkit-text-emphasis-style: dot;
  -webkit-text-emphasis-position: under;
  font-size: 300%;
}
```

```html
ieuw
```

However, it is not widely supported yet. See [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-emphasis) for full details.

Firefox supports it since version 46, or since version 45 if you enable `layout.css.text-emphasis.enabled` flag.

Chrome supports it since version 25, but needs the `-webkit-` vendor extension.

Note the standard `text-emphasis-position` uses a 2-value syntax (for horizontal and vertical writing modes, respectively), but there is a [suggestion](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2015Dec/0199.html) to allow 1-value syntax too. However, `-webkit-text-emphasis-position` doesn't allow the 2-value syntax, only the 1-value one.

Comment: That's genuinely beautiful.

Comment: In Japanese, this style is widely used and known as "kenten" (圏点) or "bouten" (傍点). In fact, I believe that is what motivated the CSS features described in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just a summary of both solutions above:

**1. Using modern CSS that sets a dot below each letter**

HTML:

```
0,<span class="dotunderletter">1</span> = 
<br>
0,<span class="dotunderletter">01</span> = 
<br>
0,001 = 1 · 1/1.000 =
```

CSS:

```
.dotunderletter {
    text-emphasis-style: dot;
    text-emphasis-position: under left;
    -webkit-text-emphasis-style: dot;
    -webkit-text-emphasis-position: under;
}
```

Result:

[image: text-emphasis-style css]

Issue: The line height changes.

**2. Using a CSS before element for each single char**

HTML:

```
0,<span class="char">1</span> = 
<br>
0,<span class="char">0</span><span class="char">1</span> =
<br>
0,001 = 1 · 1/1.000 =
```

CSS:

```
.char {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.char::before {
    content: '.';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -0.5em;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Result:

[image: CSS single char]

Issue: Each char needs to be put into a span element. But the line height does not change and it works in most of the browsers.

Thanks to hon2a and Oriol for their helpful answers!